# Script error "fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable".. will failing lines be retried?

Tags: scripting, background-process, error-handling

I'm running a ping script that backgrounds ping calls.

`#!/bin/bash
for ip in $(seq 100 210); do
        ping x.x.x.$ip -c1 |grep "bytes from" |cut -d " " -f4|cut -d ":" -f1 &
done`

If I receive the error `fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable` during an iteration of the loop, has that iteration failed irreversibly or will my script automatically try to rerun when the resources are available?

Answer (score 2):

The OS cant restart a command that failed, on its own. You could however, build such a mechanism into your script. 
When fork fails, it returns -1 and the child process is not created.
The above error is due to **EAGAIN**. check resource limits (ulimit and memory). relevant sections from the man pages below --

```
RETURN VALUE
        On  success,  the  PID  of the child process is returned in  the parent, 
and 0 is returned in the child.  On failure, -1 is returned in
 the parent, no child process is created, and errno is set appropriately.

EAGAIN fork() cannot allocate sufficient memory to copy the parent's page tables and 
allocate a task structure for the child.

EAGAIN It was not possible to create a new process because the caller's RLIMIT_NPROC 
resource limit was  encountered.   To  exceed  this  limit,  the
process must have either the CAP_SYS_ADMIN or the CAP_SYS_RESOURCE capability.
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question is if that line has failed irreversibly or if it will rerun automatically when resources become available.

Comment: No. The OS cant restart a command that failed on its own. You could however, build such a mechanism into your script.

Comment: Thank you. If you edit the original post I can mark it as the answer.